# Flutter: Send List to backend using Dio package

Tags: flutter

I'm using Dio package to communicate with my backend, I want to send two list, here is the structure of both:

List 1:

```
[{"from": "arabic", "to": "english"}, {"from": "arabic", "to": "france"}]
```

List 2:

```
['arabic', 'english', 'france']
```

I'm sending them as fromData, and the reason why I use formData is that I'm sending files too along with those two list so I can't use `application/json`

the two lists are from type `List<dynamic>`

Anyone know how what is the proper way to send them ? because when I send them directly without any editing I can't parse them when I get them back

Comment: Try doing these two calls separately. Even if they are on the same "form", you can still send the files and the json data in different calls to your backend.

Comment: I try sending the list seperatly but when I get it back it is in the form: `"[{\"\\\"from\\\"\":\"\\\"arabic\\\"\",\"\\\"to\\\"\":\"\\\"english\\\"\"}]"`

Comment: I send it like this: `'tr_languages': jsonEncode(_translatorModel.fromTolang),`